# windows server 2008 trial antivirus

Tags: windows-server-2008, anti-virus

Can you recommend me a good antivirus for windows server 2008?

Please send the download URL, because i downloaded many and while installing it tell me that the system is not supported.

i want any antivirus trial version so i can try before buy.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/58810/windows-server-antivirus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Register with McAfee](https://secure.nai.com/apps/downloads/free_evaluations/survey.asp?type=d&prodid=2796&mktg=ESD345&bu=McAfee&region=us&segment=small&RefreshPartner=UNITED%20STATES), and then download [McAfee ViruScan Enterprise 8.5i](http://www.mcafee.com/us/enterprise/products/system_security/servers/virusscan_enterprise.html).  It'll run on all versions of Windows Server 2008, and it's pretty much the same as all the other virus scanners for Windows Server products.

Answer (score 0):

AVG Business Version

This is the professional level version of AVG, not the free edition. You can get the standalone clients or go all out with a dedicated AVG server to manage client installs of AVG.

You can download trials and read more at: http://www.avg.com/us-en/download

I have used this one personaly in a corporate environment and it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

The reason most anti-virus applications are failiing to install is because you're installing them on a 'server' rather than a 'client'. Alot of those application will check and make sure that it's not being installed on a server on purpose.

You can also download a trialware version of [Symantec Endpoint Protection](http://www.symantec.com/business/products/trialware.jsp?pcid=pcat_security&pvid=endpt_prot_1) and test that application on your server also.

Good luck and hope this helps some.